# Autocomplete Jquery UI with JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

This example works great for what I need: [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/massimo-cassandro/pen/NqRmMe/)

But I need to call city values from an external JSON.

How can I adapt this example to call an external JSON?
Something linke this:

```js
$.getJSON(
"http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=?&q=" + request.term,
function (data) {
    response(data);
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The method $.getJSON() will do exactly that. It's just shorthand syntax for $.ajax(). You can load the JSON from the external API and then run whatever comparsions/checks you need.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/  <- more examples and documentation

Comment: I wouldn't put it in the array like that. You should make the ajax call and then do something like .push the results into the array.